# Как в ProgressBar установить количество ячеек?

Tags: java, android

Я не понимаю, как в прогресс бар установить нужное мне кол-во делений? есть метод который мы вызываем для установки прогресса `pb.setProgress()` но как он знает какое в нем содержится кол-во делений 5 или 10 или 58? Ни в одном примере я этого не увидел вот и не пойму? Как он это понимает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `myProgressBar.setMax(int max)` или `myProgressBar.getMax()`

Comment: + по дефолту, если не указать `.setMax(int main)`, он устанавливает 100, кажется.